# How to get all data when the condition doesn't match or doesn't found

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I want all the lines found in the database whose ack_sequence is less than the ack_sequence whose ack_pointtype = 'SUB-ENSEMBLE-JDM'. The problem is that for ack_event that have no ack_pointtype = 'SUB-ENSEMBLE-JDM', it randomly selects a random ack_sequence and returns elements whose ack_sequence is lower than this value. The expected response is all the lines in the database corresponding to the ack_event. Can you help me please? Thanks in advance.

Here's my code:

```
select rownum, t.ack_sequence , t.ack_pointtype from (select * from r5actchecklists a2 where 
a2.ack_sequence < nvl((select a3.ack_sequence from r5actchecklists a3 where a3.ack_pointtype = 'SOUS-ENSEMBLE-JDM' and a3.ack_event = a2.ack_event),99999999) 
and 
a2.ack_event = 28447879  --28447879 --
and a2.ack_pointtype = 'ENSEMBLE' order by a2.ack_sequence desc) t;
```

PS: AM using oracle 11g

Try the "with" option but it doesn't work. The expected return is all the lines in the database corresponding to the ack_event if there is no ligne with ack_pointtype= 'SOUS-ENSEMBLE-JDM'

Comment: Hi - please update your question with 1) The table definitions/DDL 2) Enough sample data for these tables to illustrate the different scenarios 3) the result you want to achieve based on your sample data. All as editable text.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand what is your query supposed to do as it uses some columns you didn't explain. But, if you literally try to code question itself:

> I want all the lines found in the database whose ack_sequence is less than the ack_sequence whose ack_pointtype = 'SUB-ENSEMBLE-JDM'

I'd try self-join:

```
select a.*
from some_table a join some_table b on a.ack_sequence < b.ack_sequence
where b.ack_pointtype = 'SUB-ENSEMBLE-JDM'
```

See if it helps. If not, consider posting sample data which illustrates the problem (that's the *source*) as well as desired result based on that sample data.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. I will try to explain it better. I want to get the ack_sequence where the ack_pointtype = 'SUB-ENSEMBLE-JDM'. for exemple if the answer is 7500, i want to get all the ack_sequence <7500. If there is no ack_pointtype = 'SUB-ENSEMBLE-JDM', then returns all data.